# How to find the wifi router ip address in my network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There are two routers in my network. The main one is used to connect wlan. The secodn router is used for my wifi. But when I check my ip address, the gateway is my main router. My question is how can I find the ip address of my second router which is used for my wifi? Thanks.

Comment: What is your outer problem? What do you need this IP address for?

Comment: I need to login to the router admin page to change some settings, for example, the wifi password, etc.

Comment: You can check the DHCP client list on the main router. The second router will be a wired client. That should help narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

As wifi is a layer 2 protocol, you won't be able to determine the IP address based on your wifi connection (IP addresses are layer 3).

So you would need to scan your network for ip addresses used, and try each one to see if you can access an admin page.  They are normally on port 80, so `http://[ip address]` should work.

You could use [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/) for this

Comment: or do a arp table lookup. On windows it will be `arp -a` to be executed from cmd. Again all the IP listed there will need to be checked. Cant have too many IPs.

Comment: @getsplashed Except the arp table is only populated with ip addresses you have interacted with so likely won't contain the APs ip address

Comment: you are right, still it is worth a try. Nmap can be very slow sometimes.

Comment: Nmap shouldn't be that slow as long as you're just doing a ping scan (or scanning for common open ports e.g. port 80 / 443). I'm guessing this is a home network and there won't be that many hosts, so a ping scan + trial and error on an alive IP address in a web browser is probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to command prompt (Win+R then cmd) and type ipconfig. The ip address on right of 'Default Gateway' is what you need.

Note: There can be more than one connection. So look for 'Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi' if you are connected through Wi-Fi. Look for 'Ethernet Adapter Ethernet', if you are connected by LAN.

Update: Sorry, I missed that crucial part of the question. As Paul said, you can scan your network for ip addresses used. You can use 'Who's on my WiFi' or any other similar software for that. This software gives mac addresses of all the devices connected. You can match the mac add with that of second router. Though sometimes some devices doesn't show up.

Comment: The OP has already stated he has checked his default gateway.